# How to handle equality constraints in this problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constraints, qcqp

Here is the problem setup

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\text{min} \hspace{4mm}  \mathbf{b}^{T}_{}\mathbf{A}^{}_{}\mathbf{b}^{}_{} \\
s.t \hspace{5mm} \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{N} \\
\hspace{9mm}b_0=1\\
\hspace{62mm}b_i=b_{i-2}b_{i-1} \hspace{5mm} \forall \hspace{5mm} 2<i\leq N-1
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{A}$ is a $N\times N$ **positive semi-definite matrix**

To handle $b_0=1$ constrain, I know I can introduce Lagrange multiplier in objective function

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\text{min} \hspace{4mm}  \mathbf{b}^{T}_{}\mathbf{A}^{}_{}\mathbf{b}^{}_{} + \lambda(\mathbf{b}^{T}_{}\mathbf{u}^{}_{}-1)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{u}_{}^{}$ is a $N\times 1$ column vector and $u_0=1$ and $u_i=0 \forall 1<i\leq N-1$.

But I dont know how to handle second set of constraints?

**EDIT: Example**

Let $N=4$. Therefore I am looking for $\mathbf{b}=[b_0 \quad b_1 \quad b_2 \quad b_3]^T = [1 \quad b_1 \quad b_2 \quad b_1b_2]^T$. How do I include $b_3=b_1b_2$ constraint in objective function

Comment: What do you mean by handle? Are you looking for theoretical results, for solving one instance for $N=4$, or for something else? Practically, it makes more sense to treat $b_0$ as fixed rather than as an optimization variable.

Comment: I am looking for a way to get rid of constraints by reformulating objective function. $N=4$ is as example. I was hoping to get an answer for $N=4$ and then look into generalizing the results for any $N$ later. I posted a reformulation here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680903/is-this-convexification-of-non-convex-constraint-correct

Comment: You can get rid of the constraints by writing all occurences of $b$ in the objective as a function of $b_1$ and $b_2$. The objective in your $N=4$ example becomes $[1 \quad b_1 \quad b_2 \quad b_1b_2]^T A [1 \quad b_1 \quad b_2 \quad b_1b_2]$. If you are hoping for a convex reformulation, you should probably give up.

Comment: Then you use a global optimization technique on the variables $b_1$ and $b_2$. You may even be able to graphically optimize this function.

Comment: So should I rely on ADMM to approximate $\mathbf{b}$. Like I fix $b_1$ and minimize over $b_2$ and then iterate for $b_1$

Comment: What you 'should' do depends on your goals. I do not think alternating optimization will find the global optimum in this case.

Comment: I did not understand when you said "depends on your goals". Goal is to find $\mathbf{b}=[1 \quad b1 \quad b2 \quad b1b2]$ which minimizes $\mathbf{b^TAb}$ for given $\mathbf{A}$. Yes I understand that ADMM has a problem of getting stuck "local minima".

Answer (score 0):

From that you have described, the second constraint in your problem happens to be a bilinear constraint, thereby making the problem non-convex. Solvers such as Baron (http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?q=baron) can be used to solve such problems.