# Is this convexification of non-convex constraint correct?

Tags: convex-optimization, constraints

**Original problem setup** [How to handle equality constraints in this problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680030/how-to-handle-equality-constraints-in-this-problem/2680116#2680116)

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\begin{array}{c}
\min_{\mathbf{b}} \hspace{4mm}  \mathbf{b}^{T}_{}\mathbf{A}^{}_{}\mathbf{b}^{}_{} \\
s.t \hspace{5mm} \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{4} \\
\hspace{9mm}b_0=1\\
\hspace{15mm}b_3=b_1b_2 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{A}$ is a $4\times 4$ positive semi-definite matrix.

I **Reformulated** this to

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\begin{array}{c}
\min_{\mathbf{b}} \hspace{4mm}  \mathbf{b}^{T}_{}\mathbf{A}^{}_{}\mathbf{b}^{}_{} + \lambda(\mathbf{b}^{T}_{}\mathbf{Z}^{}_{}\mathbf{b}^{}_{}-1)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Z} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

**My Question:**

1. Are (1) and (2) exactly same?
2. Does (2) result in convexification of non-convex constraint $b_3=b_1b_2$
3. If (2) is correct, then do we have a closed-form solution for $\mathbf{b}$

(Can someone please edit to place $\mathbf{b}$ exactly below min)

Comment: There really is nothing new here above and beyond the discussion in your other question [How to handle equality constraints in this problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680030/how-to-handle-equality-constraints-in-this-problem). As LinAlg said over there, if you're trying to find a convex reformulation, you should give up. Your problem simply isn't convex.

Answer (score 0):

For (1) and (2) to be the same, you have to specify $\lambda$. But even if you add $\max_\lambda$ after $\min_b$, they are not the same.
The term in the Lagrangian sets $b_0^2 -2b_1 b_2 + 2b_3^2 = 1$, which does not guarantee that $b_0=1$ or that $b_3=b_1b_2$.

The formulation is also not convex, because for that you need $A+\lambda Z$ to be positive semidefinite.